# Gradle: buildscript's resolution strategy

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to set the resolution strategy for the builscript, so that the version of a gradle plugin can be set centrally? For example:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin'
    }
}

apply from:   'common.gradle'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

common.gradle:

```
allprojects { project ->
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework.boot' and details.requested.name == 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin')
                    details.useVersion '1.3.1.RELEASE'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried about 100 different variants of the above, all result in an error saying the spring boot gradle plugin version can't be resolved (which is still empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach to centrally set the plugin version: use init.gradle

In your init.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    ext.springBootGradlePluginVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
    println "spring-boot-gradle-plugin version set in init.gradle to $springBootGradlePluginVersion"
}
```

Then in your individual projects:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootGradlePluginVersion"
    }
}

apply from:   'common.gradle'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

You can either use a global init.gradle in your home folder, or invoke it per project while running gradle with the `-I` command line option.

Comment: I suppose you could do the same thing using gradle.properties